# echo 'pcm.!default { type plug slave.pcm 'hw:Loopback,0,0" }' >> ~/.asoundrc

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, sh

Running this through sh but I get serversetup.sh: 18: serversetup.sh: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Comment: Cause you have an unterminated quote string.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with pcm.!default { type plug slave.pcm "hw:Loopback,0,0" }